# Slow MySQL in VMWare, but Apache works ok

Tags: mysql, performance, apache, vmware

I have OSX running VMWare with W7 Pro. This machine is configured to bridge the network adapter, so it's in the same network of OSX but with a different local IP. I installed Apache and MySQL, and I use virtual hosts; so far, so good. Any virtual hosts that I create that don't use MySQL (just static HTML or PHP sites) load really fast on OSX's browsers, but sites that need to use MySQL take a long time to load. I've investigated a lot (as far as my language understanding allows) and the only solution that worked partially is to use

```
skip-name-resolve
```

This accelerated the loading time from 10 seconds to 8 or 7, but it's still annoying for development, and more if other sites load immediately. I appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: Your grammar/spelling wasn't too bad, actually. Good luck finding a resolution for your issue (I'm not an expert in this field)!

Comment: what about connecting to mysql with the command line client? the Mysql connection is TCP/IP or socket?

Comment: thanks for your answers :)
in command line client works really fast. but i dont know how to connect by socket.